# AppCode doesn't prompt RxSwift classes and some other installed CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, jetbrains-ide, appcode, app-code

I have installed newest version of RxSwift by CocoaPods.

While trying to use simple elements of RxSwift, like `NotificationsCenter.default.rx` it doesn't prompt methods to use. Interestingly sometimes it prompts for other pods and sometimes not for the rest so I have to open XCode for checking code correction.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for [this problem](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-14763) to be fixed, sorry for that.

UPD: fixed in 2018.1 EAP, see [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/objc/2018/01/appcode-2018-1-eap/)

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue in version 2018.1. Method prompts for RxCocoa aren't working and cmd+b on the "rx" in button.rx shows the "Cannot find declaration to go" error popup. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I experience that a lot as well. One of the ways that I make it work if one of my CocoaPods is not installed correctly is to remove the pods and the .xcworkspace file, and then close xcode, and do a pod install. This should help.

Hope it helps :)

--- Edit ---

If that doesn't help, try to remove the import RxSwift, and do a clean and build again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually kind of have autocompletion in Appcode if you declare your type explicitly. The only issue is you will have to look up the `Base` for `Reactive<Base>` since Appcode considers all `rx` extensions to be `NSObject` by default. For example:

```
import RxSiwft
import RxCocoa

...

(UIButton().rx as Reactive<UIButton>) //Autocompletion will work
```

Answer (score -1):

You should import RxSwift ,then command + b